# Same Dynamic JS Function Handling Different Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, append

I have a lil' program-thingy going on up in this club, I have an object that I can drag around. What if I want to be able to drag around more objects, but each separately? I would like to be able to do this with the same JS function, like this maybe:

```
<div id="obj1" ... ></div>
<div id="obj2" ... ></div>
<div id="obj3" ... ></div>
           ...
<script> 
... 
function dragAround() { 
... 
document.getElementById("obj1, obj2, obj3")
... 
} </script>
```

Would that work? Can I drag around each object separately like that, with an  `id` for each? But now, to the tricky part: what if I make a button that will append (jQuery-append) new objects, and also give each new object a new `id` via appending?. And: can I make the new `id`:s appear in the JS-function, in the `document.getElementById(" here ")`? Without having to, beforehand, write a bunch of `id`:s  in there? Can I set up a jQuery-thingy that will append things, but within a JS function?

To conclude: How can I drag around my objects, without giving each one its own drag-around function?

Best regards!

Comment: Sorry @DalHundal don´t know what happened. Your edit was probably good tho, can you suggest a new (if you want he points or stuff)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily using jQuery UI Draggable https://jqueryui.com/draggable/. There's no need to assign an id to each element, you can accomplish this using a class. For dynamically added elements, you can invoke the `draggable()` function at the time that you append it.

Let's assume the html markup looks like this:

```
 <button id="addButton">Add New Square</button>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="draggable">Original</div>
    <div class="draggable">Original</div>
    <div class="draggable">Original</div>
  <div>
```

You can use this script to attach the draggable function to existing elements:

```
<script>$(".draggable").draggable();</script>
```

You can also bind to the click event of the button to add new elements to the container div.

```
<script>
$("#addButton").click(function() {
    var $newElement = $("<div class='draggable dynamic'>Dynamic</div>");

    $(".container").append($newElement);

    $newElement.draggable();
  });
</script>
```

You can see this full code in action, in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/tofazalute/edit?html,css,js,output